# Searching for all unlinked documents between Mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My goal is to search for posts to an API that have not received any delayed callback response. I'm willing to use the MongoDb console so without implementing DBRef neither merging both documents into one. The structure could be defined as follows:

Post to API:

```
posts
{
  "keyword":"Some keyword",
  "post_date":"03-08-2014"
},
{
  "keyword":"Some other keyword",
  "post_date":"03-08-2014"
}
{
  "keyword":"Some other keyword but no callback received",
  "post_date":"03-08-2014"
}
```

API callback response:

```
callback
{
  "keyword":"Some keyword",
  "reception_date":"03-08-2014"
  "response" : "Hey"
},
{
  "keyword":"Some other keyword",
  "reception_date":"03-08-2014"
  "response" : "Hey"
}
```

Based on keyword, and matchin post_date with reception_date, I'm willing to find all posts that have Not received any callback.

Any idea on how I may do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand how the problem is framed. How is this data delivered to you? Just as this pair of collections of JSON documents? If so, I'd suggest shoving all the posts into a collection with `response : false`, indexing on keyword or a combination of keyword and date, then running an update per callback document, matching on keyword and setting `response : true`.

Comment: Yes: I'm sending the post json to an API. Then, after some time between 5 minutes and 24h, I should receive a callback response but it's not always the case. 
The callback response also contains a url to get the final results. I think it's better to add the final results in a different collection, but keeping all posts and callback received in the same collection as you mentionned (for debug information)